# When Header is added the Protected Route is not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am doing a simple application which has a protected route.

The code goes like:

```
function App() {


return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/protected"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <ProtectedExample />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Private Route is :

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthStatus } from "../hooks/useAuthStatus";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { loggedIn, checkingStatus } = useAuthStatus();

  if (checkingStatus) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
  return loggedIn ? children : <Navigate to="/sign-in" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Protected Route

```
import React from "react";

const ProtectedExample = () => {
  return <div>ProtectedExample</div>;
};

export default ProtectedExample;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" fixed="top">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <Link to="/">Vivans</Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Link to="/sign-in" className="me-4">
            Login
          </Link>
          <Link to="/protected">ProtectedRoute</Link>
        </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

When i remove the header component in App.js

The output is :
[image]

But when i add header component in App.js

The output is :
[image]
It doesn't return ProtectedExample as expected to be .

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it might be rendering it. It maybe invisible for us because of CSS styling.

```jsx
<Navbar bg="light" variant="light" fixed="top">
```

In the above line, you have given the *NavBar* to be `fixed` at the top. So the `ProtectedExample` would be behind the `NavBar`

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Try changing your component like this,

```jsx
const ProtectedExample = () => {
  return <div style="margin-top: 3em">ProtectedExample</div>;
};
```

This might bring the content downwards to make it visible.

Comment: return <div style={{ marginTop: "4em" }}> ProtectedExample</div>; and it works , Thank you. This is the small change required

Comment: But why this happens, Because Header is on the top and then it is followed by protectedExample. Then why are they stacked . How can i get them in the column

Comment: It gets stacked because of `fixed`. `posititon: fixed` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. 
To get it in column, this is the workaround. We shall have a `margin-top` for the body content.